# How do I validate uniqueness within scope when I swap values?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this model called LocationRule. LocationRule has_many :rule_parts, and accepts_nested_attributes_for :rule_parts.

RulePart has an attribute called position. I validate the position this way:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :position, scope: :location_rule_id, if: -> (record) { record.location_rule_id = record.location_rule.id if record.location_rule.present?; true }
```

There is one problem. When I try to swap position values in rule parts I get an error on both rule parts saying:

```
Position has already been taken
```

I tried to work my way round the problem trying to remove errors after validation, but before save. Is there a better way to do it at the validation stage?

### Update 1

I decided to validate duplication of rule parts in location rule validators. But I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

```
validate :check_uniqueness_of_rule_part_positions

def check_uniqueness_of_rule_part_positions
  positions = []
  errors = false
  self.rule_parts.each do |rp|
    if positions.include? rp.position
      rp.errors.add(:position, 'is already taken')
      errors = true
    else
      positions << rp.position
    end
  end

  self.errors.add(:priority_numbers, 'Duplication detected') if errors
end
```